# How to parse json data with retrofit for objects within object?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I have seen many examples of JSON used for retrofit on the web but unable to find the type of json structure i have. I could not manage to solve it. I have following json data for which i am trying to show in my android app with java:

```
{
  "main": {
 "data": [
      {
        "Date": "2020-06-15",
        "name": "mary",
        "address": "NY"
      },
      {
        "Date": "2020-06-15",
        "name": "bob",
        "adress": "LA"
      },
      {
        "Date": "2020-06-15",
        "name": "John",
        "address": "CA"
      }
     ]
   }
}
```

In addition i got following model classes:

```
-----------------------------------com.example.Datum.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Datum {

@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private String date;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;

public String getDate() {
return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
this.date = date;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
this.address = address;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example {

@SerializedName("main")
@Expose
private Main main;

public Main getMain() {
return main;
}

public void setMain(Main main) {
this.main = main;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Main.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Main {

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = null;

public List<Datum> getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```

However i am unable to make interface class and use the models in retrofit. Please suggest appropriate way to do it with example. Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Why do you need an interface class here? And I hope you generated this model using jsonschema2pojo

Comment: @vinv: i am getting empty result.

Comment: @Sumit Sahoo: to define retrofit calls like "@GET("/")
Call<Main> getMain();"

Comment: Do check @milad answer. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a `class` like this :

```
public class Main{

    @SerializedName("main")
    private Main main;

    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<Datum> datas;

    public void setMain(Main main){
        this.main = main;
    }

    public Main getMain(){
        return main;
    }

    public void setCustomers(List<Datum> datas){
        this.datas = datas;
    }

    public List<Datum> getDatas(){
        return datas;
    }
}
```

And as you write your `Datum`  `class` something like this :

```
public class Datum {

@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private String date;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;

public String getDate() {
return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
this.date = date;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
this.address = address;
}

}
```

And you should have and API `interface` like this :

```
@GET("/")
Call<Main> getMain();
```

Comment: where does customers come from?

Comment: @Bishwash, Change it to data , i updated my answer.

Comment: It should be @SerializedName("Date"). Rest all is fine.

Comment: @vinv , The response that come from server is date , please check the question again!!